# Использование таймера

Tags: c#

Всем привет, скажите вот у меня объявлена переменная **timer** равна 0, так вот при запуске она увеличивается на 1, и потом идёт сравнение

```
if(timer >= 2)
 this.Hide();
```

И этот код не работает, программа просто запускается, и не сворачивается... почему так?

Comment: ну наверное потому, что после увеличения переменная timer равна 1. А 1 < 2 и условие не выполняется.

Comment: Извините, ошибочка. Нет она объявляется в самом начале, а не в определённом событии.

Comment: мне кажется маловато кода, для этого, может больше контекста?

Comment: Да у меня там больше ничего и нету, это всё в событии Form_Load.

Comment: @Angus123, сделайте пошаговою отладку и скажите чему равна переменная timer в момент сравнения.

Comment: при запуске чего она увеличивается? если при запуске все программы, то после любого запуска переменная ваша timer всегда = 1.

Comment: Нет, переменная у меня хранится в классе Settings... она задана нулю, но потом я сохраняю её постоянно Settings.Default.Save();

Answer (score 2):

Как работает Ваш код - "если(1 больше или равно 2) прячем форму".

Так как 1 не больше и не равно 2 условие не выполняется... Тайна раскрыта?

Answer (score 0):

если видите, что условие с переменной не работает, то перед `if` можно вывести значение переменной на консоль для отладки, и тогда все встанет на свои места.